# Please explain the syntax

Tags: scripting

Can someone explain the syntax of the following commands? II know what they do but was having a hard time getting the syntax,

```
find / -type f -exec grep -H 'text-to-find-here' {} \;
cat access.log | cut -d '"' -f3 | cut -d ' ' -f2 | sort | uniq -c | sort -r
sudo cat error_log.20150205 | grep mpmstat | grep -v "," | cut -d: -f4- | grep -v ":"   | sed -e's/rdy//g' |  sed -e 's/bsy\|wr\|ka\|log\|dns\|cls\|rd/,/g
```

Comment: As someone detailled your commands, job's done. But should you be on your own, you can also give [http://explainshell.com](http://explainshell.com) a try. It is great for beginners.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. While this time someone has taken the time to answer all three of your questions (you might want to [accept the answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), by the way), you should avoid asking more than a single question at a time. Next time, ask a separate question for each of the commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find`
     `/` → Search from root
     `-type f` → only select file (`f`)
     `-exec ....{} \;` → execute the command inserting the found (file) names for `{}` one by one
     `grep -H 'test-to-find` → execute this grep on every file found by `find`

---

`cat access.log |` → output file to stdout and pipe into next command
     `cut -d '"' -f3 |` → split lines on `"` and output only field 3, pipe into next command
     `cut -d ' ' -f2 |` → cut field 3 based on spaces and take second field, pipe into next
     `sort | uniq | sort -r` → sort the output, remove duplicates, sort in reverse order (`-r`)
(this last one can be done with some `sort` versions with `sort -ur` in one command, and the first one is a superfluous `cat` as you can write `< access.log cut -d '"' | ....` )

---

`sudo cat error_log.20150205 |` → execute cat with root permission (access rights on the file?)
     `grep mpmstat |` → only select lines with the word `mpmstat`
     `grep -v "," |` → deselect (`-v`) any line with a comma
     `cut -d: -f4- |` → split into fields based on ':' as delimiter, take fields nr 4 and up.
     `grep -v ":" |` → suppress lines with ':' (unlikely there as this was the split character before)
     `sed -e's/rdy//g' |` →  replace `s` the sequence `rdy` with nothing all over (`g`) each line
     `sed -e 's/bsy\|wr\|ka\|log\|dns\|cls\|rd/,/g` →  replace various alternatives (`bsy,`wr`, etc, separated by`\|`) by a comma

Comment: Cool. You might have summed it up like: *badly written*

Comment: @mikeserv If I had read ahead beyond the first one more closely (the first on is IMO not that bad), I might have skipped the whole.